# Reputation with editing "to be closed" questions

Tags: support, editing, reputation

As an avid editor for the main site, I have taken quite a liking to the 2 rep I get for passing my time, however when I see a question that is off topic, and yet messy, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825850/64gb-bootable-usb-is-not-recognized-in-bios-and-cant-boot), I still feel the need to edit it and make it pretty ^v^ My question is ***not if I should*** do this, but if the question is closed as off topic if I keep the 2 reputation from when it was edited, because I was looking back at my reputation log, and saw this:

[image]

If anyone has insight on this I'd be glad for any help.

Answer (score 7):

You do get to keep the +2 reputation from closed questions.

However, you will lose the +2 reputation if the question is actually deleted.

Comment: Unless they are deleted.

Comment: @MarkKirby Added picture

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice That is my point, you keep it if you edited the question before it was closed (not sure about after voting) but as with anything on the site, you loose the rep when it gets removed, of course, this happens to off topic questions.

Answer (score 7):

Please do not edit off-topic questions. You waste reviewers' time on that. Flag an off-topic questions to be closed.